# How to import docker image from local machine into plesk

Tags: node.js, docker, plesk, plesk-onyx

I have small API app written in node.js and i want to run in docker on plesk.
I successfully create image and run in container on local docker machine.
I have Plesk Onyx 17.5.3 with docker extension in version: 1.3.1-126.
And now I`m not sure how to run this my image run in plesk.

I tried:

1) With command **docker save -o output-path image-name** export image to .tar file.
[image]
2) This .tar file upload on plesk to docker extension.
[image]
3) After upload create image name "sha256:038a9". BTW: My name of docker image is wapi.
[image]
4) And if i use "Run (local)" so i can`t set port mapping. After click on OK button show **Error: {"message":"No command specified"}**
[image]

Can you somebody help me, please?

PS: If you want see anything (dockerfile etc.) so write it. :)

**dockerfile**

```html
FROM node:7
WORKDIR /app
COPY package-lock.json .
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY /dist .
CMD npm run docker_start
```

Comment: yes can you show dockerfile?

Comment: @sanathmeti done. But i say, application is running ok on local docker.

Comment: FYI: You can`t set port mapping because automatic port mapping is checked in your picture.

Comment: @dskow Yes, i know, but if i uncheck, so nothing happened. This is i mean.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Sadly there seems to be no solution to this? We can also not use Dockerhub (especially public one!).

Answer (score 6):

Plesk Docker Workaround:
Upload your Docker-Image with FTP. Than use a shell and run the command "docker load -i [yourimagefile.tar]" to deploy the image in the repository of the PLESK-Server. After this you can use your image under PLESK without pain;)

Answer (score 0):

That because docker image is been loosing the CMD or ENTRYPOINT metadata information while doing

```
docker export 

docker import
```

Its been discussed here

```
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8334
```

You can publish your image to dockerhub ( private/public ) then import that in plesk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but "docker export" export a container’s filesystem, not image. via: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/

Comment: I used "docker save" to export image from local.

Comment: BTW i used export, but it is the same!

Comment: yes in that process it skipped the CMD / ENTRYPOINT metadata, you can have try with dockerhub

Comment: we need a solution without dockerhub

Answer (score -1):

There are few ways to export/import containers and images.

**Export container**

```
docker export container-name | gzip > Zip_File_Name.gz
```

**Import container**

```
zcat Zip_File_Name.gz | docker import - container-name
```

**Docker save container/image in zip file**

```
docker save -o Zip_File_Name.tar container_name
```

**Docker load image from zip file**

```
docker load -i Zip_File_Name.tar
```

Comment: this comment was useful, but not the right solution I think